# I am getting 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' into sql table instead of getting actual data entered in text boxes

Tags: c#, mysql

Can someone please help me figure out why I am getting `'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'` in MySQL database instead of actual values being entered in the text field. The code I am using is below ..

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
string queryStr;
string connString=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnectionString"].ToString();
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
queryStr = "";
queryStr = "INSERT INTO seework.userdata (First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name, Email_Address, Phone_Number, Username, Password)" + "VALUES('" + firstnameTextBox + "','" + middlenameTextBox + "','" + lastnameTextBox + "','" + emailaddressTextBox + "','" + phonenoTextBox + "','" + usernameTextBox + "','" + passwordTextBox + "')";
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
cmd.ExecuteReader();
conn.Close();
```

I have tried all I could but still no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the TextBox itself to the database using the query. You need to pass the text instead. For this you can use [`.Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the TextBox control. Which gives you the Text/Content inside the Textbox Control. And one more advise for you. Use Parameterized queries instead for cuch queries to avoid [`Sql Injection`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

For example:

```
queryStr = "INSERT INTO seework.userdata (First_Name, Middle_Name)VALUES(@fName,@mName)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=firstnameTextBox.Text ;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mName",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=middlenameTextBox.Text; 
// Build your command like this
// Execute the command then
```

Comment: Thanks So much for such a quick and elaborate reply.

Comment: Cool...! Happy to help you. Always try to use Parameterized queries or else stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.Text` after the name of TEXTBOX.
For Example :-

```
string insert = "insert into table_Name (Name, Contact, Email) values ('" + txtname.Text + "', '" + txtcontact.Text + "', '" + txtemail.Text + "')";
```